# Ошибки в сборке проекта после git clean -xdf

Tags: python, django, git, pip

Сегодня при установке библиотеки scipy возникли ошибки, и pip предложил мне выполнить  `git clean -xdf`.

Я сделала бэкап всего проекта и выполнила команду. Установка всё равно не удалась, и я восстановила удалённые папки из бэкапа, но теперь при загрузке проекта возникают ошибки в модулях, к которым я не имею отношения.

Например, не хватает `menu.html` в папке проекта `\templates\gis\index.html` строка 77, при этом вся папка `\templates\gis` отслеживается в гите:

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: menu.html
```

index.html cтроки 75-77:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<div id="map"></div>
{% include "menu.html" %}
```

В папке `\templates\gis` есть файл `menu.html`. Над проектом я работаю не одна, но мои коллеги пока не отвечают. Есть мысли, что проблема в запросе csrf-token, потому что в логах питона выводится

> UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext."A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "

Помогите разобраться, что привело к ошибке и как её решить.

Comment: Поскольку вы использовали флаг `x`, могли грохнуться нужные для проекта файлы, пути к которым есть в `.gitignore`. Какие-нибудь файлы конфигурации, например.

Comment: {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide = сообщение только говорит о том, что отдаете данные без значения csrf_token, такое бывает если не передаем context, отдавая ответ простой строкой через response.

Comment: По основной проблеме. 1) окружение python, видет ли пакеты с приложениями, можно проверить через manage.py shell, попробовав импортировать 2) файл settings, путь к папке шаблонов и способам обхода. 3) проверить что файлы в одной ветке

Comment: Оказалось, что index.html обращается к menu.html из другой папки, что немного странно. После загрузки menu.html рансервер запустился, но сайт стал нерабочим. Полетели все стили, настройки в путях гитигнор. Пришлось удалить виртуальную среду и настроить всё заново, чтобы заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При git clean -xdf слетели настройки gulp, bower, package.json. Решением стало полностью пересобрать проект, начиная с переустановки виртуальной среды и заканчивая фронтендом. Проект работает.